# Can we apply the Fundamental theorem of integration on $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, cauchy-principal-value, interval-arithmetic

So, we're given $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ in $[-1;1]$.

AFAIK, the theorem only works if $f(x)$ is continuous, which in this case it isn't for $x=0$. So we cannot use the theorem.

If we just integrate it:

$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x}\,dx=ln|1|-ln|-1|=0$

Is this right? I'm just getting started and need a little help!

Comment: The integral is divergent, but you should look at the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

Comment: No, it's not right, and it's not right because of the reason you mentioned: $f$ is not continuous at $0$. In fact, $f$ is not even bounded on $[-1,1]$ (even after arbitrarily defining it at the origin), so it's not properly Riemann-integrable. What is true though is that $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}[\int_{-1}^1f(x)\,dx+\int_{\epsilon}^1f(x)\,dx]=0$; but this is simply because $f$ is an odd function.

Comment: @peek-a-boo so let me get this straight, if the function isn't defined at a point, we cannot integrate it if the interval contains that point, right?

Comment: @GL02: even if you *defined* the function at $0$ to be $0$ (or whatever), the integral is still divergent because $\int_0^1\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x$ is divergent.

Comment: Technically, no, just look at the definition of a Riemann integral. We need a function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$. Of course, if we have a function $\phi:[a,b]\setminus\{p\}\to\Bbb{R}$ which is defined on the whole interval minus a point, then we can define $f(x)=\phi(x)$ for $x\neq p$, and then define $f(p)=0$ for example. Now we can ask the question of whether $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable. In your case, $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$, and I consider $f(x)=\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. But still because $f$ is unbounded there, it's not Riemann-integrable.

Comment: No, you are on the right track, but the situation is not that simple; you have to examine what is known as an improper integral.  Suppose that $f(x)$ is defined everywhere on $[a,b]$, except at point $c$, where $a < c < b.$  Then, you have to examine two distinct integrals: $I_1(r) = \int_a^r f(x)dx$ and $I_2(s) = \int_s^b f(x)dx.$  Then you have to determine whether $\lim_{r \to c} I_1(r)$ and $\lim_{s \to c} I_2(s)$ exist.  If both exist, then the integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ exists and is equal to $$\lim_{r \to c} I_1(r) + \lim_{s \to c} I_2(s).$$  ...see next comment

Comment: If either limit does not exist, then $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ does not exist.

Comment: You aren’t given any such function “in $[-1,1].$”

Comment: The proposed function is not bounded on $[-1,1]$. Hence it is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I found this video of Dr. Peyman which explained it pretty well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kDjt1gT33U&ab_channel=DrPeyam

Answer (score 1):

It is not right in because you integrated over an interval with zero as an x value. This has 1/0 which is undefined. If you are in a higher level course you could use the Cauchy principal value and get 0 but, if you are just starting it is wrong.
This is one of those questions that depends on the course.